# Barman >1.5.1 for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, backup, postgresql, header-file

I use [Barman](http://www.pgbarman.org/) 1.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

For several weeks, barman has been working smoothly. Some days ago I noticed something strange.

Instead of backups I find other files in the `<SERVER>/base/` directory of some of the backups (e.g. `autoselect.h` in `.../base/20170816T230003` and `fcall.hpp`, `parameterized.hpp`, `parser_binder.hpp` in `.../base/20170805T230003`). Most of the other backups are fine.

Any ideas what this could be and why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

In $PGDATA/postgresql.conf, change the listen_addresses parameter:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Restart postgres.

Comment: The parameter is already set to `listen_addresses = '*'`.